# Split a restaurant bill, including tip

Tags: python, beginner

Just looking for a little feedback on the below tip calculator I've coded rounding the output to nearest 2 decimal places.

Just wondered if it was readable and code friendly?

```
bill = float(input("What was the total bill? $"))
tip = float(input("How much tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15  "))
no_of_people = float(input("How many people to split the bill?"))

cost_of_tip = bill / 100 * tip
total_cost = (bill + cost_of_tip) / no_of_people
final_per_person = round(total_cost, 2)
final_amount = "{:.2f}".format(final_per_person)

print(f"Each person should pay: ${final_amount}")
```

Comment: Looks good for beginner code! Very clear. I don't think you need to both `round` the sum as well as display it with two decimals `:2f` though, you're kind of doing the same thing twice.

Comment: I once worked for a company that spent a few hundred thousand dollars fixing the "we used `float` for money` mistake.

Comment: Floats are fine to split a dinner bill though.

Comment: One thing that is not accounted for -- in either question or answers so far -- is that dividing money is tricky business. For example, imagine that I decide to split a $10 bill with 2 other friends: the answer is NOT that we should each pay $3.33 dollars, but instead that 2 should pay $3.33 and one should pay $3.34. Are you interested on feedback on this logic, or are you happy with 3.33 because bill splitting was just an excuse to write some code?

Comment: To make certain not to split cents, use `floor` to round down. If the sum of `final_per_person` adds up to less than `total_cost` then report that `x` cents are outstanding, or distribute the missing cents randomly among the persons.

Comment: Why have separate input for the bill and the tip? If the bill is 34.27 and add 15% tip, will you really pay 39,41 or do you give 40?

Comment: Because of the $-sign I'm assuming this is meant to be used in the USA. If you want to use it on holiday keep in mind that there are valuta that don't have denominations smaller then 1 or even higher (Korean Won starts at 10) and there are non-demical valuta too (most are historic tho https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-decimal_currency#List)

Comment: This (and the answers I skimmed) need validation on the "people" variable. If the user enters zero for the number of people, an exception will be thrown. Perhaps default to 1 if less than 1

Comment: @CrisLuengo until you leave the money on the table and the the restaurant realizes that some of the money is missing. (ok, that's 1 cent. still)

Comment: @Jungkook there are quite a few countries using the peso (or dollar, depending) sign, beside the USA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peso#Countries_that_use_pesos and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar# (For holidays, I'd say the main thing to keep in mind is that countries have very different ways of looking at tips)

Comment: @njzk2 I discuss that in my answer below.

Answer (score 16):

**Confusing variable name**. Is the tip an amount or percentage?
I assumed the former based on variable name, but a commenter
has corrected me.

**Keep calculation and presentation logically separate**. You don't
need to create a variable for the rounded amount. Just compute
the per person cost in the natural way. When you are ready to display
that value in a human-readable form, format it as needed.

```
# Get user input.
bill = float(input('Bill: '))
tip_pct = float(input('Tip percentage: '))
npeople = int(input('People: '))  # int() seems more appropriate.

# Calculation.
per_person = bill * (1 + tip_pct / 100.0) / npeople

# Presentation.
message = f'Per person: ${per_person:.2f}'
print(message)
```

**Next step: start putting your code in functions**. As you try to write
programs longer than a few lines, adopt a strict discipline of putting
all code in functions and never relying on global variables (constants
are fine). There are many reviews on this site emphasizing such points.
The logical divisions illustrated above (collecting input, performing
calculations, presenting results) will continue to be relevant
as you start using functions.

**Another next step: validating and generalizing the collection of user input**. Currently, you ask the user for 3 numbers, but people make mistakes.
There are many reviews on this site illustrating how to write a simple
function taking a message (eg, "Enter the bill") and returning
a validated value, with the opportunity to recover from user errors.

Comment: You can infer from the output that the tip is a percentage, not a fixed amount.

Comment: @ades When the user is prompted with `"How much tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15  "`, it's not at all obvious that they are asked for a percentage. Once they receive the output `f"Each person should pay: ${final_amount}"`, yes, they can infer it was a percentage. But that's a bit late.

Comment: If you know how tips work in the US, it's clear this must be a percentage.  It would make no sense for $10, $12, or $15 to be the only tip options.

Comment: The receipts I've seen all ask for a tip amount, not percentage. If anyone is using the software, copying receipt values into the input, they'll go very wrong. Also, it doesn't make too much sense to ask for "10, 12 or 15" when you're not checking the value anyway. Renaming the prompt to "How much tip .. give (percentage)" would definitely improve UI.

Comment: @nasch who says this is used in the USA?

Comment: Maybe this is a Python thing, but I don't see why you'd use `tip_pct` instead of `tip_percent`. Same with `npeople` instead of `num_people`. That style can add ambiguity  with no real benefit.

Comment: @njzk2 The dollar sign would tend to indicate that, though it isn't 100% conclusive.

Comment: @nasch not conclusive indeed. There are dozens of countries using that sign as local currency symbol.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider Not convinced. Selecting names involves tradeoffs, and the broader context is crucial. In the current context, the names used have approximately zero ambiguity, but the heavier alternatives suggested by you would be fine as well.

Comment: @njzk2 In how many of those is tipping at a restaurant customary, and would typically be either $10, $12, or $15?  If the answer is zero, I submit that this is clearly a percentage, not an absolute value.

Comment: @nasch I haven't been to all of them. But I don't think ignorance is a justification for random assumptions.

Comment: @njzk2 Look, the calculation of cost_of_tip alone makes it quite clear that this must be a percentage and not an absolute value.  You have made me regret ever bringing up anything about the US since that is not even necessary to reach that conclusion, so if that was your goal, congratulations.  If you wanted to contribute something useful I'm afraid you have not gotten there yet.

Comment: @nasch "the calculation of cost_of_tip alone makes it quite clear that this must be a percentage and not an absolute value." I agree. In at least a few of the places I know that use $ for currency symbol this conclusion makes sense. I only wanted to point out that there are other places in the world beside the USA, and that jumping to such conclusion, that using $ means USA, doesn't help. I'll remain convinced that this is useful by itself, and I'll do without your validation, if I really must, thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

There's a bug in the logic: If I select 0% tip, it is quite possible that adding the rounded amounts each person pays don't add up to the bill total. You should probably use `ceil` instead of `round`, to ensure you round up, never down.

Of course giving a negative tip percentage also makes you not pay the bill total, but that would clearly be user error. It's good to guard against user error, but it is not strictly a bug in the code.

I would suggest though that on input you make it clear that you are looking for a percentage when asking about the tip. `"How much tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15  "` could be interpreted as a dollar amount rather than a percentage.

Answer (score 10):

Get into the habit of localisation instead of hard-coding currency formats and symbols.

There's not much of a point to asking for a tip among a list of options if you aren't going to validate it. Even if you were to validate it, I would enforce "between 0 and (perhaps) 100".

The tip amount itself isn't used; so just get the total cost directly.

Don't round - let `locale.currency` choose the number of decimal positions.

"number of people" isn't a `float`; it's an `int`.

### Suggested

```
from locale import localeconv, setlocale, LC_ALL, currency

setlocale(LC_ALL, '')
symbol = localeconv()['currency_symbol']

bill = float(input(f"What was the total bill? {symbol}"))
tip = float(input("How much tip would you like to give? %"))
no_of_people = int(input("How many people to split the bill? "))

total_cost = bill * (1 + tip/100)
final_per_person = total_cost / no_of_people
final_amount = currency(final_per_person)

print(f"Each person should pay: {final_amount}")
```

Comment: I think the localization overshoots the target here and does so inconsequently. What about localizing the prompts?

Comment: @RichardNeumann Which is it - too much ("overshooting") or too little (not enough localisation)? Localisation is not all-or-nothing - it's certainly possible to over-engineer it, but it exists on a continuum. IMO the offered approach is a useful taste for the OP to see how locale-agnostic formatting is done.

Comment: Fair enough. I think that the (partial) localization is too much for the task at hand and too little for *actual* localization, though.

Comment: @RichardNeumann how is it only partial localisation?

Comment: @theonlygusti because if all you do is localize the currency, then it's still only suitable for English speaking locales.

Comment: @nasch good for tourists

Comment: @theonlygusti quite the contrary, assuming that this is targeting the way tips work in a particular country.

Answer (score 6):

## Separate your concerns

Split input parsing from your calculation logic. Read and parse the input in one step and do the calculation in a separate function.

## Use fitting data types.

Using `float` as a data type can have nasty side-effects. Consider using `decimal.Decimal` instead.
Also the three parameters to calculate the bill belong together, since they are only meaningful in their combination for the given use case. Hence, they should be contained in a common data structure.

## Use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard

To prevent your script from executing when being imported for re-use in other scripts.

## Suggested change

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import NamedTuple


class SplitBill(NamedTuple):
    """A split bill with a tip."""

    bill: Decimal
    tip: int
    people: int

    @property
    def tip_cost(self) -> Decimal:
        """Return the cost of the tip."""
        return self.bill * self.tip / 100

    @property
    def total_cost(self) -> Decimal:
        """Return the total cost with tip."""
        return self.bill + self.tip_cost

    @property
    def cost_per_person(self) -> Decimal:
        """Return the cost for each person."""
        return round(self.total_cost / self.people, 2)


def read_split_bill() -> SplitBill:
    """Interactively reads a split bill."""

    return SplitBill(
        Decimal(input("What was the total bill? $")),
        int(input("How much tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15  ")),
        int(input("How many people to split the bill?"))
    )


def main() -> None:
    """Reads the values and calculates a split bill with a tip."""

    split_bill = read_split_bill()
    print(f"Each person should pay: ${split_bill.cost_per_person}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is good advice, but maybe not suitable for a beginner?

Comment: A class for this is bad

Comment: Can you explain the need for creating a class for this? Can you justify that the class, representing a bill that includes a tip (expressed as a percentage), is in charge of reading the input form the user?

Comment: @theonlygusti Funny, that I gave arguments as to why the class is a good idea and you just counter with a bland statement without giving a reason. *Why* is a class for this bad? *Why* do *you* think that my arguments for a class are invalid or insufficient, *Where* is your review?

Comment: @njzk2 Indeed, having the class be responsible for reading is suboptimal. A free function for this may be better. As to why I considered a class in the first place, see my post. Within the scope of the problem, the values are only meaningful in combination and hence belong together.

Comment: @RichardNeumann `read_split_bill` should really be a `classmethod` something like `split_bill_from_userinput` imho. Also the printing in `main` belongs to `__str__`

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I got mixed feedback now. Some think that it should be a classmethod, which I initially disgned it as, others think it should not be, which I am inclined to agree with after some more consideration. But maybe this shows, that there is no obvious correct answer to this question.

Comment: Re: beginner issue, I think this is a good example of a basic child class with type hints, but depending on how much of a beginner they are, they might have no idea what this is or how to even google about it. I think even just a short explanation could help, e.g.: _This class uses inheritance to extend the built-in `NamedTuple`, and it also uses type hints like `: int` and `-> None` to indicate variable/return types._